# Non-dev asking for assistance with apex trigger and test class

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I am making a change to our sales process, which conflicts with an Apex trigger and test class that my predecessor developed.

I've updated both the trigger and the test class to reflect correct picklist field values.

When I test the test class in the sandbox, the only error I receive is:

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false
Class.GtmhubOpportunityTriggerTestClass.validateTeamMemberNotAdded: line 40, column 1
```

Line 40 of the test class reads:
System.assertEquals(true, otm.isEmpty());

Since this is 1 of 5 tests, and all of the others passed, I thought it might pass code coverage in production. I pushed the change set and validated with only the Trigger in the change set. I get a fatal error of 0%.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

I'm unsure of how to get the test class to stay within the code block. If anyone can advise there, it'd make it much easier to read.

Thanks in advance!

**Trigger is here:**

```
    trigger GtmhubOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update, after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
            if (o.OwnerID != null) {
                OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember(OpportunityId=o.Id, UserId=o.OwnerId, TeamMemberRole='Account Executive', OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit');
                insert otm;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Convert Currency
        Map<ID, DatedConversionRate> isoWithRateMap = new Map<ID, DatedConversionRate>([SELECT NextStartDate, StartDate, IsoCode, ConversionRate FROM DatedConversionRate]);
        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
            if (opp.Amount != null) {
                Decimal convertedValue;
                for (DatedConversionRate dcr: isoWithRateMap.values()) {
                    if (dcr.isoCode == opp.CurrencyIsoCode) {
                        if (opp.CloseDate >= dcr.startDate && opp.CloseDate <= dcr.nextStartDate) {
                            convertedValue =  opp.Amount / dcr.conversionRate;
                        }
                    }
                }
                opp.Converted_Amount__c = convertedValue;
            } else {
                opp.Converted_Amount__c = 0;
            }
        }
        // Validate Contact Role
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
        Set<Id> oppList = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
            oppList.add(o.Id);
        }
        Set<Id> noConRole = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT OpportunityId Id
            FROM OpportunityContactRole
            WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppList
            GROUP BY OpportunityId
        ]).keySet();
        for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
            Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
            Integer changeCount = 0;
            for (String str : M.keyset()) { 
                try { 
                    if(opp.get(str) != oldOpp.get(str)){
                        changeCount += 1;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.debug('Error: ' + e);
                }
            }
            if (opp.StageName != '1 - Qualification' && opp.StageName != 'Renewal Anticipated'&& UserInfo.getProfileId().subString(0,15) != '00e4W000002TtYI') {
                if (!noConRole.contains(opp.Id)) {
                    if (changeCount > 0) {
                        opp.addError('You must add a Contact Role -- convert a Lead and add to this Opportunity, or add an existing Contact to the Opportunity -- before updating the Opportunity.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test class is here:**

```
    @isTest
private class GtmhubOpportunityTriggerTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateTeamMemberAdded() {
        // Insert User
        User[] u = TestDataFactory.createUsers(1);
        // Insert Account
        Account[] a = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        // Insert Opportunity
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp',
                                        StageName='1 - Qualification',
                                        CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                        AccountId=a[0].Id,
                                        RecordTypeId='0124W0000007bPpQAI',
                                        OwnerId=u[0].Id);
        insert o;
        // Retrieve the opportunity
        o = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        // Retrieve the opportunity team
        OpportunityTeamMember otm = [SELECT Id, UserId, OpportunityId, TeamMemberRole, OpportunityAccessLevel FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId =:o.Id];
        // Test that otm is there with the right values
        System.assertEquals(o.OwnerId, otm.UserId);
        System.assertEquals('Account Executive', otm.TeamMemberRole);
        System.assertEquals('All', otm.OpportunityAccessLevel);
    }
    static testMethod void validateTeamMemberNotAdded() {
        // Insert Account
        Account[] a = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        // Insert Opportunity
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp',
                                        StageName='1 - Qualification',
                                        CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                        AccountId=a[0].Id,
                                        RecordTypeId='0124W0000007bPpQAI');
        insert o;
        // Retrieve the opportunity
        o = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        // Retrieve the opportunity team
        List<OpportunityTeamMember> otm = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>([SELECT Id, UserId, OpportunityId, TeamMemberRole, OpportunityAccessLevel FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId =:o.Id]);
        // Test that otm is null
        System.assertEquals(true, otm.isEmpty());
        System.assertEquals(null, o.OwnerId);
    }
    static testMethod void validateNullConvertedAmount() {
        // Insert Account
        Account[] a = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        // Insert Opportunity
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp',
                                        StageName='1 - Qualification',
                                        CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                        AccountId=a[0].Id,
                                        RecordTypeId='0124W0000007bPpQAI');
        insert o;
        // Retrieve the opportunity and update
        o = [SELECT Id, Comments__c, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        o.Comments__c = 'Test update';
        update o;
        // Retrieve the opportunity
        o = [SELECT Id, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        // Test that converted amount is 0
        System.assertEquals(0, o.Converted_Amount__c);
    }
    static testMethod void validateUSDConvertedAmount() {
        // Insert Account
        Account[] a = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        // Insert Opportunity
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp',
                                        StageName='1 - Qualification',
                                        Amount=100,
                                        CurrencyIsoCode='USD',
                                        CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                        AccountId=a[0].Id,
                                        RecordTypeId='0124W0000007bPpQAI');
        insert o;
        System.assert(o.Id != null);
        // Retrieve the opportunity and update
        Test.startTest();
        o = [SELECT Id, Comments__c, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        o.Comments__c = 'Test update';
        update o;
        Test.stopTest();
        // Retrieve the opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp = [SELECT Id, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        // Test that converted amount is 100
        System.assertEquals(100, opp.Converted_Amount__c);
    }
    static testMethod void validateEURConvertedAmount() {
        // Insert Account
        Account[] a = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        // Insert Opportunity
        Date closeDate = date.newinstance(1960, 2, 17);
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp',
                                        StageName='1 - Qualification',
                                        Amount=100,
                                        CurrencyIsoCode='EUR',
                                        CloseDate=closeDate,
                                        AccountId=a[0].Id,
                                        RecordTypeId='0124W0000007bPpQAI');
        insert o;
        System.assert(o.Id != null);
        // Retrieve the opportunity and update
        Test.startTest();
        o = [SELECT Id, Comments__c, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        o.Comments__c = 'Test update';
        update o;
        Test.stopTest();
        // Retrieve the opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp = [SELECT Id, Converted_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:o.Id];
        System.debug('opp: ' + opp);
        // Test that converted amount is 121.95
        System.assertEquals(121.95, opp.Converted_Amount__c.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That one test fails because it asserts that team member was not created for the Opportunity on insert. But on the other hand, you have the next logic in the Trigger that makes this test impossible to pass, because it literally creates team member every time.

```
if (o.OwnerID != null) {
     OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember(OpportunityId=o.Id, UserId=o.OwnerId, TeamMemberRole='Account Executive', OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit');
     insert otm;
}
```

> I pushed the change set and validated with only the Trigger in the
> change set. I get a fatal error of 0%.

What does it mean? Did you deploy only the trigger without unit tests? If yes, then it will fail because it should have at least 75% of code coverage to deploy them.

Therefore, update the Trigger's logic to not create a team member for some cases or remove the `validateTeamMemberNotAdded()` method from the test class and deploy them both.

Comment: Thank you for your response Anton.

Per your suggestion, I’ve remarked out the method.

I reran the test against the Apex test class, and it came back with 4 pass remarks.

Unit testing yielded 88% code coverage of the trigger I’m trying to promote.

I promoted the trigger and test class to production using a change set, and ran tests only against the trigger itself. However, I still get the 0% code coverage error. 

I’d appreciate any additional guidance you can give me.

Comment: Good. I see there are custom fields in your code. Try to deploy them first, then the trigger and apex test. Sometimes it fails because can't access the new fields during the deployment.

Comment: Thanks Anton.
Comments__c and Converted_Amount__c are already in production. 
To clarify the validation process, if I just specific the trigger that is included in the changeset, will validation only use that version of the trigger, rather than the one that is already in production?

Comment: Sorry, can't suggest the right answer here. I'm not using change sets for deployments

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help, Anton.